# Existence of measure on $[0, 1]$ such that $\int f d\mu = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Does there exist a measure $\mu$ on the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of $[0, 1]$ such that $\int f d\mu = \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ for every increasing $f: [0, 1] \to [0, \infty)$?

I have no idea on where to start with this. This exercise came from a chapter about Stone's condition but I don't see why that is relevant?

Edit: Using @gregmartin's hint I believe we could write $\int f d\mu = \int g + \lambda s \space d\mu = \int g \space d\mu + \lambda \cdot \int s \space d\mu = g(0) + \lambda$. This looks a lot like Dirac's measure so I would assume that such a $\mu$ does indeed exist.

Comment: Your condition could be the definition of such a measure (if it is one).  Then check to see whether the conditions of a measure are satisfied.

Comment: Isn't this just the Dirac measure at 0?

Comment: The Dirac measure concentrated on $0$ is pretty close in that it satisfies your condition for every $f$ that is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be $\int f d\mu = f(0)$?

Comment: @Krijn Yes, if $\mu = \delta_{0}$ then $\int f \, d\mu = f(0)$.

Comment: @Krijn My guess is that you can show there is no such measure by showing that it would have to be $\delta_{0}$ because of its behavior on the continuous functions, but wouldn't work then for functions discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: @QuinnCulver Well, my first idea was kind of like that. I was looking for two functions $f$ and $g$ that would satisfy this condition, with $\int f + g d\mu \neq \int f d\mu + \int g d\mu$. However I could not find them.

Comment: Hint: every increasing $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ can be written as $f=g+\lambda s$, where $g$ is continuous at $0$ and $s(x)=\mathop{\rm sgn}(x)$ (that is, $s(0)=0$ and $s(x)=1$ for $x>0$). Indeed, $\lambda\ge0$ is the size of the jump discontinuity of $f$ at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such measure can exist.

Consider the Borel-measurable functions
$$
f_n(x) := x^{1/n}
$$
and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if } x = 0 \\
1 &\text{ if } 0 < x \le 1
\end{cases}
$$
For a fixed $x$, $f_n(x)$ is an increasing sequence converging to $f(x)$.  Moreover,
$f_n$ and $f$ are increasing ($f$ not strictly), so we have
$\int f_n \; d\mu = 0$ and $\int f d\mu = 1$.
But this contradicts the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).